# Postgres11.5, Planning time on partitioned table is too high

Tags: postgresql

Facing performance issue after adding more partitions (~4000 total on that table), simple query shows:
 Planning Time: 3112.604 ms
 Execution Time: 1.936 ms
I think 3 sec on planning is too much. Any idea how we can reduce planning time please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We've got the same time, although not as many partitions as that does seem a bit excessive, the majority of the time is spent planning when the constraint specifies one parition only. Surprised it takes postgres that long to say parition_space in 755 and figure out which child table (partition) to use.